# Is there a way to fine-tune a general model with calibration data and then perform inference for an AWS SageMaker model?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I have a saved ML structure with weights for a model on SageMaker. Is there a way so that I am able to call the SageMaker endpoint with calibration data (based on a single user), update the weights for the model, and the perform inference on new testing data with the updated model, all in one call?

I am trying to do this for multiple users.

Currently, I can only think of creating a new endpoint for fine-tuning, and then deleting the endpoint after inference finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to fine tune the model on the endpoint?

1. Usually you would use a Training Job to fine-tune and once you are happy with the fine-tuned model you can seamlessly deploy the new model version to the endpoint.
2. By default SageMaker endpoint support blue green deployment. Other deployment strategies can be seen here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/take-advantage-of-advanced-deployment-strategies-using-amazon-sagemaker-deployment-guardrails/
3. If you want to hose multiple models for different users you could look at using a SageMaker Multi-Model endpoint. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-model-endpoints.html

Comment: Let me rephrase. I need to calibrate and further train the model on a per-user basis. I can't fine tune the model before deployment. I am trying to have it so that on a single call, provided calibration data and inference data, the model will train further on the calibration data, and then perform inference on the inference data. If it helps, the model is a computer vision model that parses a video.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "provided calibration data and inference data, the model will train further on the calibration data, and then perform inference on the inference data".

If you want to add pre-processing logic you can use an inference.py script

Comment: I have a base model. Every time a user calls my AWS model (whether through an endpoint or an API), I want to fine-tune the base model on custom data from the user. Then, I want to perform inference on the (also provided) user data, with the new fine-tuned model. This whole process should repeat for every user, or essentially every time the model is called. Fine-tuning should happen on the base model ever call.

Comment: Curious what model you are using? Are you able to quickly accomplish this say locally ?